# Django / Postgres Group By Aggregate

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, group-by

I've have an issue regarding queries with a group by clause.
Lets assume I have the following Django-Model:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    value = models.FloatField()
    relation = models.ForeignKey('OtherModel')
```

If I want to do a query where I group SomeModel instances by OtherModel and annotate the latest date:

```
SomeModel.objects.values('relation').annotate(Max('date'))
```

This is all great, but as soon as I want to add a filter on the already annotated queryset I am getting nowhere:

```
SomeModel.objects.values('relation').annotate(Max('date')).filter(value__gt=0)
```

This would indeed filter out all the value != 0, however I only want it after the annotations took place. If the latest date of a relation has the value 0, I want it to be filtered out!

Comment: I dont think its possible in django ORM, unfortunately. Not without raw(), and RawQuerySet is more limited than normal QuerySet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the value in the annotate filed and then you can filter over it. Your ORM query becomes

```
SomeModel.objects.values('relation').annotate(Max('date'), value=F('value')).filter(value__gt=0)
```

This should give the value you require